# Output issue while time conversion(milliseconds)

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am calculating latency in milliseconds. The values in the list are no of operations, I am dividing it by the no of flops of the system that is 7.2 Gigaflops, will give me the time.  I would like to know how to convert this into milliseconds.

```
     macc=[3699376640,3699376640,924844544,924844544]
     for i in range(1,len(macc)
            macc_latency=i/(7.2*10**9)
            print(macc_latency)
```

I had a look online for calculating latency. Link to the article [link](https://www.quora.com/How-does-an-adding-layer-in-a-convolutional-neural-network-affect-the-execution-time). I would like to know how this is converted to nanoseconds.

```
      t=(2*79,350/10*10^12)= 15.87 Nanoseconds.
```

Thanks, help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that your range loop does not work as you intend: you need to loop through the contents of "macc", not (as you stated) through the numbers [1-3]. And: you are missing a ")" and a ":" at the end of the loop-head.

Comment: Hi @PawelBoe, you are right, I have updated the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Second is 1000 Milliseconds. So if you have a value that is given in seconds (assuming your Gigaflops is given as Measurement/second), just multiply it by 1000:

```
 macc=[3699376640,3699376640,924844544,924844544]
 for m in macc:
        macc_latency=m/(7.2*10**9)
        macc_latency_ms *= 1000
        print(macc_latency_ms)
```

Without additional information, you cannot gain precision here.
Edit: code is now valid python